# couldn't open .xsn file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, infopath

I am getting the following error message when I try open an attachement .xsn file.

"Infopath cannot create a new blank form. The file is not a valid XML file."

I have used

```
Response.ContentType = "application/x-microsoft-InfoPathFormTemplate";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=filenam1.xsn");
```

Could you please let me know what could be wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: What behavior are you expecting? For InfoPath designer to render the attached document?

Comment: Yes, I was able to open file Infopath designer from my disk. After uploading I couldn't open the file.

Comment: I can't prototype this right now, but it seems like the InfoPath Filler application is being triggered rather than Designer, hence the message about expecting an xml file. Maybe a ContentType issue?

Comment: what does `filename1.xsn` look like?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem.

When you use IE (IE 10, in my case), the file is never actually downloaded. Instead, IE spawns InfoPath as a child process, providing the URL of the host page as a parameter.

[image]

Because you're using Response.TransmitFile (or similar), the URL of the host page will not match the URL of the Form Template. You're getting the invalid xml error because InfoPath is trying to parse the HTML of your webpage as a Form Template.

[image: InfoPath is terrible]

[There's very little you can do about this, from the IE perspective](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/iewebdevelopment/thread/751F4958-2A97-4911-9718-CE2FDF1407AB), it appears. From the link:

> 3) In IE the method that decides how to display content looks at mime type, the first bytes of the file, the extension and a registry setting.  If your content looks like i.e. HTML, that's how it'll be displayed.
>
> 5) There is no known fix for the issue, so you have to live with it.
>
> 6) Content-Disposition has no impact on the problem.

My recommendation would be to expose an actual URL to the form template, if possible, either through an HTTP handler or some other mechanism, unless someone here knows of a better solution.